# ProjectDepthToCamera returns 0 for all the xyz of pos3d

Tags: c++, realsense

I am not sure why all the x, y, z values happen to be zero in pos3d in the following code. Please suggest fixes:

```
/***
Reads the depth data from the sensor and fills in the matrix
***/
void SR300Camera::fillInZCoords()
{

    PXCImage::ImageData depthImage;
    PXCImage *depthMap = sample->depth;
    depthMap->AcquireAccess(PXCImage::ACCESS_READ, &depthImage);
    PXCImage::ImageInfo imgInfo = depthMap->QueryInfo();
    cout << "inImg->QueryInfo() " << depthImage.format << endl;
    PXCPoint3DF32 * pos2d = new PXCPoint3DF32[depth_width*depth_height];
    int depth_stride = depthImage.pitches[0] / sizeof(pxcU16);

    for (int y = 0, k = 0; y < depth_height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < depth_width; x++, k++) {
            pos2d[k].x = (pxcF32)x;
            pos2d[k].y = (pxcF32)y;
            pos2d[k].z = ((short *)depthImage.planes[0])[y* depth_stride + x];
        }
    }

    //Point3DF32 * pos3d = NULL;
    PXCPoint3DF32 * pos3d = new Point3DF32[depth_width*depth_height];
    PXCPoint3DF32 * vertices = new PXCPoint3DF32[depth_width * depth_height];
    Projection * projection = device->CreateProjection();
    projection->ProjectDepthToCamera(depth_width*depth_height, pos2d, pos3d);
    cout << "x is " << pos3d->x*1000 << endl;
    cout << "y is " << pos3d->y*1000 << endl;
    cout << "z is " << pos3d->z*1000 << endl;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a correct verified answer to get the XYZ Map out of depth image UV-Map:
    Status sts = sm ->AcquireFrame(true);

```
    if (sts < STATUS_NO_ERROR) {
        if (sts == Status::STATUS_STREAM_CONFIG_CHANGED) {
            wprintf_s(L"Stream configuration was changed, re-initilizing\n");
            sm ->Close();
        }
    }

    sample = sm->QuerySample();
    PXCImage *depthMap = sample->depth;
    renderd.RenderFrame(sample->depth);
    PXCImage::ImageData depthImage;
    depthMap->AcquireAccess(PXCImage::ACCESS_READ, &depthImage);
    PXCImage::ImageInfo imgInfo = depthMap->QueryInfo();
    int depth_stride = depthImage.pitches[0] / sizeof(pxcU16);
    PXCProjection * projection = device->CreateProjection();
    pxcU16 *dpixels = (pxcU16*)depthImage.planes[0];
    unsigned int dpitch = depthImage.pitches[0] / sizeof(pxcU16);
    PXCPoint3DF32 *pos3D = new PXCPoint3DF32[num_pixels];
    sts = projection->QueryVertices(depthMap, &pos3D[0]);
    if (sts < Status::STATUS_NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf_s(L"Projection was unsuccessful! \n");
        sm->Close();
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < num_pixels; k++) {

            if (pos3D[k].x != 0) {
            cout << " xx is: " << pos3D[k].x << endl;
            }
            if (pos3D[k].y != 0) {
            cout << " yy is: " << pos3D[k].y << endl;
            }
            if (pos3D[k].z != 0) {
            cout << " zz is: " << pos3D[k].z << endl;
            }
          }
```